# Calculadora que sea notación polaca inversa javascript

Tags: javascript

Gente, tengo que hacer una calculadora que imprima el resultado de la cuenta pero de manera postfija, lo que vengo haciendo es esto:

```
function crearCalculadora (){

    let objeto={}; 

    let acum=0

    objeto.sumar=function(num){

        return acum+=num

    }

    objeto.restar=function(num){

        return acum-=num

    }
    objeto.reset=function(){

        return acum=0}

    objeto.valor=function(){

        return acum }

  return objeto

 }
```

De esa manera mi funcion se ejecuta bien, pero de manera "Normal" que tengo que hacer para que pase de esto:
`2+3+4` 
a esto
`2 3 4 + +`

Comment: ¿Qué tal si haces dos arrays que se replecente de esta manera: `{"number":[],"signo"};` y recorres la cadena almacenando cada char int en una variable hasta que llegue la signo y cuando eso suceda se añade el número al la matriz que te dije: `operation["number"][I]+=string_number; operation ["signo"][i]=string[I];` y después si quieres puedes hacer otro bucle que recorra los dos arrays por separado llenando un string de la manera que quieres: Primer bucle: `string+=operation["number][I]+' ';`. Segundo bucle: `string+=operation["signo"][i]+' ';`